# WP7 SoundEffect volume decreases

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I can't figure this one out.  If I click on a textbox, it sets up a timer to fire x number of times a minute.  The timer seems to work fine, but the lower the cycles per minute, the lower the volume that the sound affect plays. I must not be understanding how the XNA framework works.

```
private System.Threading.Timer tmrMetronome_m;

private void tbTempo_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;
    int iBeatsPerMinute = int.Parse(tb.Text);

    int iMS = 1000 * 60 / iBeatsPerMinute;

    if (this.tmrMetronome_m != null)
    {
        this.tmrMetronome_m.Change(new TimeSpan(0), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, iMS));
    }
    else
    {
        this.tmrMetronome_m = new System.Threading.Timer(MetronomeTick, null, new TimeSpan(0), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, iMS));
    }
}

private void MetronomeTick(object state)
{
    using (System.IO.Stream strWAV = TitleContainer.OpenStream("wav/Beat.wav"))
    {
        SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(strWAV);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have finally purchased a developer license, and deployed the softawre to the phone.  No issues when on the physical device.  At this point it appears that only the emulator has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't some other issue at play here?  Could the beats possibly be overlapping to create the impression of being louder when they occur more often?

I recreated pretty much your exact code above in a quick XNA project, and did not experience the loudness issue.  I was not -- obviously -- using the same audio sample though.

Comment: I don't think an overlap is happening, because they would have to be perfect overlaps - and I'm testing at different tempos all the way from 40 to 200, so if there was overlaps, they would mostly be irregular at most tempos.  The project doesn't use xna anywhere else or play any other sounds either.  I'm at a total loss.

Comment: I've finally purchased a developer account and deployed to my phone. No issues on the real phone.  I think this is a problem with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try moving that Stream reading out to the initialization somewhere. Store the sound effect contents into a SoundEffect variable during your app loading time and then call Play() on this variable during the MetronomeTick.

Depending on your wants, an alternative is to only store a SoundEffectInstance variable, and then during load time, load it up like so:

```
using (System.IO.Stream strWAV = TitleContainer.OpenStream("wav/Beat.wav"))
{
    SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(strWAV);
    soundInstance = effect.CreateInstance();
}
```

To play it, just call Play() on the SoundEffectInstance object.

Of course, because you're only keeping one instance, two of these sounds will never overlap (not sure of what you want). Either way it's worth trying if this problem still persists.